# Xdebug not working after I install PHP and configure settings

Tags: php, xdebug

I installed Xdebug on PHP 7.3 using `pecl install xdebug`

When I add these settings to `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` and reload Apache the page fails and says no data sent to server.

```
xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.halt_level=E_WARNING|E_NOTICE|E_USER_WARNING|E_USER_NOTICE
xdebug.scream=1
```

Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Are those actually commented out like in your question..?

Comment: is the path is correct? something like this: `zend_extension="/usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so"`

Comment: @zack6849 I apologize no they are not commenting in server

Comment: I'm not sure why are you using pecl to install the library? You seem to be running Linux so you are probably better off using a php-repository for your distro and installing the packages using the packaging system of your distro.

Another problem that could exist is a failing webserver configuration. But that config is not included in your question.

Comment: @jkushner set xdebug.remote_log=/PATH/TO/LOG.log and tell us what it gives you. Also your post has almost no detail and as a result is impossible to attempt to solve

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton what am i missing from my post? ive got the xdebug install configurations and the issue has to do with the installation?

Comment: A copy paste of the error message the page is giving you, if you comment out remote_enable does it still fail (if so what is the new error), xdebug log results, apache log results. If all that fails a minimal example would be great, after all it's pretty clear that your settings are fine as no one else can reproduce and settings aren't the issue unless you've done something like get the zend_extension path wrong. You also haven't attempted to follow the steps @yivi highlighted, or if you have you haven't gotten back to us on it

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton i commented out remote_enable, added xdebug log path to php.ini, and checked apache error logs. cannot access something as simple as <?php phpinfo();?>. and no logs

Comment: Well if it still fails after commenting out remote_enable then xdebug isn't the cause. Also if xdebug does anything it goes into the logs, something is probably wrong with your apache setup. That should definitely give you access logs at least?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> (In the original version of your question, your configuration was commented out, now you've edited that bit out, leaving the next couple of paragraphs kinda out of the loop)

Despite the documentation [stating that the has character  (`#`) is no longer recognized as a valid comment character since PHP 7.0](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#configuration.file.changelog):

[image: PHP Changelog]

it seems that php will happily treat those lines as commented nonetheless in configuration files. Everything afer the hash is ignored by the interpreter.

So those configuration lines are completely ineffective.

To verify that your configuration is being loaded, create a simple file like this:

```
<php
phpinfo();
```

Loading this file will tell you everything about PHPs configuration. If Xdebug has been successfully loaded, you'll see something like this:

[image: phpinfo output]

And down below the configuration settings loaded:

[image: phpinfo output]

These are the most important settings, that actually load and enable the Xdebug extension:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

**Important**: You need to check that `/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so` actually exists, and if not find the actual location of your xdebug module.

The next line assumes that the webserver and the browser are installed on the same machine on the same IP, which might be true for a simple setup:

```
 xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
```

As an alternative, you can tell Xdebug to connect back to whichever IP has made the orginal request

```
 xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
```

With the following line you are telling on which port your IDE is listening to. It's 9000 by default, so you'll normally would not need to set it unless you need to listen to a non-standard port (e.g. debugging several projects at the same time, against different interpreters). But normally, you can omit this line safely:

```
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Once the module is loaded and enabled, you can also configure some Xdebug settings using an environment variable. Specifically `xdebug.remote_host`, `xdebug.remote_port`, `xdebug.remote_mode` and `xdebug.remote_handler`

E.g:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=192.168.0.3 remote_port=9005"
```

Comment: In config files, the ``#`` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Derick, [the fine manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) says otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

- xdebug is not compatible with php7.3 for releases < 2.7
- you may install xdebug beta version which is make-compatible with php7.3:

```
pecl install xdebug-beta
```

https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1584

---

**Update:**

XDEBUG has released a new version, and it has different configurations. The new version is compatible with PHP>=7.4. Check it out:

https://xdebug.org/docs/install

Answer (score 2):

To install xdebug on php7.3 run the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.3
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.3
```

Now download source code and install by running the following commands:

```
cd /tmp

wget http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.8.0.tgz
tar -xzvf xdebug-2.8.0.tgz
cd xdebug-2.8.0
phpize
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```